# Pass BSTR from C++ to C#

Tags: c++

I have C# project "X" ,I have exposed methods in it to the C++ project "Y".

X has method signature as follows -

```
public void WriteInformation(string sInfo)
{
    m_logger.ErrorInfo("{0}", sInfo);
}
```

As I am exporting it to a C++ using .TLB file I checked declaration of this method in .tlh file which generates on #import of .tlb file.

```
virtual HRESULT __stdcall WriteInformation ( /*[in]*/ BSTR sMsg ) = 0;
```

I am calling this method in C++ project and passsing argument as follows -

```
oLog->WriteInformation(BSTR("Info write successful"));
```

Issue here is the string passed from C++ always becomes garbage or null , I debugged it and I can see value of sInfo is always garbage or null.

Please let me know what method should be followed to pass string from C++ to C#.

Answer (score 3):

You try to pass an ANSI string in place of BSTR. BSTR must be a wide character string. Also you shouldn't pass a string literal, you should properly allocate a BSTR using `SysAllocString()` (or better yet) a wrapper class like `ATL::CComBSTR` or [`_bstr_t`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthfhkd6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Btw `_bstr_t` has a constructor that will accept `const char*` and do the ANSI->UTF16 conversion for you.

Comment: modifying oLog->WriteInformation(BSTR("Info write successful"));  to oLog->WriteInformation(_bstr_t("Info write successful")); solved the problem.

Comment: @Rahul: Great, that's what should have happened.

Answer (score -1):

I dont think its possible to interact with C++ and C# directly. I had interacted using a C++/CLI wrapper.